# Telnet server: is it good practice to keep connections open?

Tags: python, sockets, server, connection, telnet

I'm working in a NetHack clone that is supposed to be playing through Telnet, like many NetHack servers. As I've said, this is a clone, so it's being written from scratch, on Python.

I've set up my socket server reusing code from a SMTP server I wrote a while ago and all of suddenly my attention jumped to this particular line of code:

```
s.listen(15)
```

My server was designed to be able to connect to 15 simultaneous clients just in case the data exchange with any took too long, but ideally `listen(1)` or `listen(2)` would be enough. But this case is different.

As it happens with [Alt.org](https://alt.org/nethack/) when you telnet their NetHack servers, people connected to my server should be able to play my roguelike remotely, through a single telnet session, so I guess this connection should not be interrupted. Yet, I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444459/python-sock-listen) that

> [...] if you are really holding more than 128 queued connect requests you are
>   a) taking too long to process them or b) need a heavy-weight
>   distributed server or c) suffering a DDoS attack.

What is the better practice to carry out here? Should I keep every connection open until the connected user disconnects or is there any other way? Should I go for `listen(128)` (or whatever my system's `socket.SOMAXCONN` is) or is that a bad practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`number` in `listen(number)` request limits number of **pending** connect requests.

Connect request is **pending** from initial SYN request received by OS until you called `accept` socket method. So `number` does not limits open (established) connection number but it limits number of connections in **SYN_RECV** state.

It is bad idea not to answer on incoming connection because:

- Client will retransmit SYN requests until answer SYN is received
- Client can not distinguish situation when your server is not available and it just in queue.

Better idea is to answer on connection but send some message to client with rejection reason and then close connection.

Comment: Awesome! Didn't know that. Thank you very much!