# Listening to an unlimited number of sockets in python

Tags: python, networking

I was wondering, if I want to listen to each socket that wants to join,
what do I need to write inside the 
sock.listen(?) 
What number goes there and tells python "I want to listen to everyone" and not to a limited number of sockets.
I thought about just putting a large number, but I feel it's not the right answer.

Thanks for the helpers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2444483/364696) where John la Rooy says:

> The doc say this
>
> > socket.listen(backlog) Listen for connections made to the socket. The
> >     backlog argument specifies the maximum number of queued connections
> >     and should be at least 1; the maximum value is system-dependent
> >     (usually 5).
>
> Obviously the system value is more than 5 on your system. I don't see
>   why setting it to a larger number would be a problem. Perhaps some
>   memory is reserved for each queued connection.
>
> My linux man page has this to say
>
> > If the backlog argument is greater than the value in
> >     /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn, then it is silently truncated to that
> >     value; the default value in this file is 128. In kernels before
> >     2.4.25, this limit was a hard coded value, SOMAXCONN, with the value 128.

Comment: But I'm working on a project and I need to listen to whoever connects, if I put just 5, I will only be able to listen to maximum 5 people. (Or I'm getting this totally wrong)

Comment: The socket is not concurrent. You can handle one request at a time, and the number you place inside socket.listen() is the backlog. The backlog is essentially a queue of unaccepted connections to respond to. If a request arrives once this queue is full it will be declined. For more detail see https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.listen

Comment: ohh, now I get it! Thank you!